# Is using new Function() unsafe in all instances?

Tags: javascript, function, security, template-literals

I'm working on a project that creates a new function, then returns an evaluated template string. My code goes like this:

```
var myString = "${hello}"
var myFunc = new Function("hello", 'return `' + myString + '`')
document.getElementById("tdiv").innerHTML = myFunc("whassup")
```

It works perfectly, as you can see on my JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nebrelbug/28c7hfm8/. However, is this a security risk? Functions automatically have strict use, so it couldn't access variables other than those I pass in. I fail to see how this would impact security at all.

If it is a security risk, please explain why. If not, will most security evaluators like 'npm audit' or Github mark it as one?

Thanks!

Comment: This might be well enough for a good start - [Why `new Function()`s are bad?](https://davidwalsh.name/new-function)

Comment: Why are you guys downvoting?

Comment: @downvoters don't just downvote. at least explain why you think this deserves a downvote. the *question itself* is not bad. the use of `function` arguably is.

Comment: I've seen several template engines using the Function constructor... what makes them safe? Or aren't they? Are there some ways that Function can be used safely?

Comment: Not a security expert, but my two cents are that the same basic principle applies as to any other parsed content: as long as the input doesn't come from an outside source, you should be safe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many things said to be "risky" are not *inherently* security risks by themselves, they're just *potentially* security risks if implemented improperly. This is one of those cases. You *could* have a script like

```
const foo = 'foo';
const bar = eval('foo');
```

This code, exactly as is with nothing else, is obviously not a security risk, but you can't necessarily count on security evaluators to completely accurately verify whether how you're implementing something is *actually* safe or not - they use programmed heuristics, rather than a human security expert examining your code for holes. As such, using `eval` and its relatives like `new Function` are *more closely correlated* with insecure code.

In my snippet, just as with your code, even if it's not a security risk, it's still a *very inelegant* way of achieving your goal. Try to find a better way of achieving it. For example:

```js
var myString = "foo ${hello} bar";
function myFunc(replaceHelloWith) {
  return myString.replace(/\$\{hello\}/g, replaceHelloWith);
}
console.log(myFunc("whassup"));
```